# div with display:inline-block margin 0 auto not center

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;">
    <input id="abc" type="button" value="button" />
</div>
```

I try to use the code above to set the width of  equal it's content, and then center it with margin: 0 auto;

But it did not work for me on any browser. Any suggestion?

BTW, when I set the width property, it works fine.

```
<div style="width: 10em; margin: 0 auto;">
    <input id="abc" type="button" value="button" />
</div>
```

Comment: Per @Xander comment, without a width, a DIV will expand to 100% of it's container.  So "margin:0 auto" isn't likely going to show any effect as you'll need something smaller than 100% width.  If you're just trying to center the button, why not just center align text?  ie. "text-align:center" in the DIV style.  I think INPUT tags are inline naturally, so it should center itself inside the DIV>

Comment: @Fozzyuw, no matter the width is necessary or not, when we set display: inline-block, the width will be set equal to its content.

Comment: Your second example works, because you removed the `display: inline-block`. When you add it back again, setting the width has no effect. See http://jsfiddle.net/anEvF/

Comment: If you stumble upon this thread but none of the answers work for you, check that your div is not floated. `margin: auto` does not play nicely with `float`.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

display:table; would position it in center too:

CSS:

```
  .button{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
<input id="abc" type="button" value="button" />
< /div>
```

Note: Using inline styles is a bad practice.

Comment: @kapa I know this is an old comment, but I would probably consider that a positive. :)

Answer (score 53):

Since you requested DIV to be `inline-block`, `text-align: center;` is the answer.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
    <input id="abc" type="button" value="button" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-align: center;` will center inline *content* of the div, not the div itself.

Comment: Pardon, forgot to erase the CSS. Sorry.

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I want to center the div itself.

Comment: Note: this discussion is outdated. The answer has been since edited to include a wrapper div, such that the inner, original div is centered. So it is what he wants.

Comment: It adds an [annoying and] unwanted thin padding below my navbar anchor tags (when I hover over them they don't get the background color), but the accepted answer doesn't. (Although I don't like the accepted answer because it's hacky to me!)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
body {text-align: center;}
```