# `margin:auto;` doesn't work on inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a "container" `div` to which I gave `margin:auto;`.

It worked fine as long as I gave it a specific `width`, but now I changed it to `inline-block` and `margin:auto;` stopped working

### Old code (works)

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.MtopBig {
    margin-top: 75px;
}
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center MtopBig" id="container"></div>
```

### New code (doesn't work)

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px;
}
.MtopBig {
    margin: 75px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center MtopBig" id="container"></div>
```

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/NDwLB/1/).

Comment: Try `display:table`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9313467/632951

Comment: Know that `margin: auto` is still 'working' but no longer centers the div. I have tried to explain this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37710665/2397550

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is no longer centered because it now flows on the page in the same way `inline` elements do (very similarly to `img` elements). You will have to `text-align: center` the containing element to center the `inline-block` `div`.

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px;
}
.MtopBig {
    margin: 75px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="MtopBig" id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 35):

**What 'auto' means:**

Using `auto` for the horizontal margin will instruct the element to fill up the **available space** (source: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-margin-auto/).

**Why 'display: inline-block' does not center:**

There is no available horizontal space in an inline setting. Before and after it are other inline elements (characters) that take up their own space. Therefore, the element will act as if the horizontal margin is set to zero.

**Why 'display: block' centers:**

When used as an element with `display: block` set to it, the available horizontal space will be the full width of the parent element minus the width of the element itself. This makes sense because `display: block` is reserving this horizontal space (thus making it 'available'). Note that elements with `display: block` cannot be placed next to each other. The only exception occurs when you use `float`, but in that case you also get the (expected) zero-margin-behaviour, as this disables the horizontal 'availability'.

**Solution for 'inline-block' elements:**

Elements with `display: inline-block` should be approached as characters. Centering characters/text can be done by adding `text-align: center` to their parent (but you probably knew that already...).

Comment: Read this and edit accordingly: https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/how-well-do-you-know-display/

Answer (score 10):

For elements with property **display: inline-block**; 
**A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes a used value of '0'.** [reference: [CSS2§10.3.9](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-width)]

Answer (score 4):

```
margin-left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

```css
.container{
  border:solid 1px red;
}

.container img{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: the resulting width will be 50%

Comment: no it won't. The element will be positioned at 50% width of the container minus 50% width of the element. The result is the element will be centred within the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/upba6c4j/2/

Comment: this is the perfect solution if you want to let the element be centered by itself and not by it's parent element

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make 2 inline divs in same line together and one of them in most right, I used width to set the first div width to 70% and remaining for the second div, I also used white-space:nowrap; to prevent wrap divs in next line (to be responsive)

this is my example

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;white-space:nowrap;">
  <div style="border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;width:70%;max-width:70%;word-break:break-word;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue;word-break: break-word;white-space: normal;">  
  hello hi hi hi;hello hi hi hihello hi hi hihello hi hi hihello hi hi hihello hi hi hihello hi hi hihello hi hi hihello hi hi hi</div>
  </div>
  <div style="border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;width:28%;height:100%;vertical-align:top;word-break:break-word;white-space;">Right Side Inline-Div</div>
</div>
```

! note white-space:normal used to prevent the inherited white-space and allow for word-break in the child containers