# Making display:inline-block moves the paragraph to left

Tags: html, css, display

Why does the div display property `inline-block` move the paragraph to left which was centered by `margin:0 auto` without display property.

```
.content
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 900px;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

The `content` is the class id of the div which has some paragraph inside it.
When I add `display: inline-block` the paragraph is moving to the left side. Why is it so?

https://jsfiddle.net/3h1wwgy6/1/

Comment: I think this is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076919/marginauto-with-inline-block

Comment: @neallred: Yes, make it duplicate

Comment: This is not really a duplicate as this explicitly asks the valid question 'WHY?'. I have tried to answer that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37710665/2397550

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DIV as **`display:block`**(block level element) has characteristic/behavior to occupy entire page width. So when you assign **auto** for margin-left and margin-right, it automatically **takes up the available space** equally on both sides. So the element will be centered based on width of its parent element.

When you change the display property of a DIV to `display:inline-block`. It takes up the best of both worlds (block & inline) i.e., You can use a definitive margins, padding like block elements AND it can follow the normal HTML layout flow like any inline element e.g., span or anchor.

So when you say **auto** to an **inline-block**, the default automatic behavior for inline-block is to **follow the normal flow** of the document (i.e., 0px).

Official definition for **auto** :

> Auto margins
>
> Depending upon the circumstances, provision of an auto value instructs the browser to render a margin according to the value
>   provided in its own stylesheet. However, when such a margin is applied
>   to an element with a meaningful width, an auto margin instead causes
>   all of the available space to be rendered as whitespace.

Comment: Auto does NOT mean its default value. I have tried to explain what 'auto' means here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37710665/2397550

Comment: @JoostS Thanks. I have corrected how I referred "auto" in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align: center` on its parent div to center a div with `display:inline-block`. As @David Chelliah said, `display: inline-block` makes it act like an inline-element.