# html form and css: cannot center items

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, center

I have some troubles to center items in html form. A very simple example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/a9cnuypz/

```css
#rectLogin {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#formLogin {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#btn {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectLogin">
  <form id="formLogin">
    <div>
      <label>Username</label>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="username" required>
      </fieldset>
      <label>Password</label>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is how appears now:

[image: actual]

and here how I want:

[image: desired]

I don't understand my mistake. I set for the relevant items (form and button) both a width and margins=auto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `display: block;` to `#formLogin` and `#btn`

```
#formLogin {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
}
```

```css
#rectLogin {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#formLogin {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  display:block;
}

#btn {
  margin: auto;
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectLogin">
  <form id="formLogin">
    <div>
      <label>Username</label>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="username" required>
      </fieldset>
      <label>Password</label>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Quick and easy. Thanks for the clarification. Need to wait few minutes to accept the answer :)

Comment: Sure!! For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076919/marginauto-with-inline-block

Comment: This link is very useful. Now I understand the difference between block and inline-block - and it make sense, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

text-align center in

```
 #rectLogin
```

And set display block, and text-align left in

```
#formLogin
```

```css
#rectLogin {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align:center;
}

#formLogin {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


#btn {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectLogin">
  <form id="formLogin">
    <div>
      <label>Username</label>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="username" required>
      </fieldset>
      <label>Password</label>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```