# Why can I not center horizontally a child element using mx-auto?

Tags: html, css, margin, tailwind-css

I am trying to center horizontally a button. This button is in a container which already centers itself using `margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto`.

unfortunately I cannot do the same for the button inside this container which would have been easier because I could have used one class for the container and the button.

I am using Tailwind classes for my project and the `mx-auto` class which is `margin-left:auto AND margin-right:auto` works for the container but not the button hence this question. Why can I not use that class for my button ?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 550px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 92px;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 /* display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;*/
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css">
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">      
            <button class="btn">boutton</button>        
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the button has `display: inline-block`, it's not about how tailwind works.
you can change the button's display to `block` or add `block` to its class (tailwind).
for more info about this checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076919/marginauto-doesnt-work-on-inline-block-elements)

Alternatively, you can set the parent's display to `flex` and center button vertically and horizontally by `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to align the button in the center of your container, you must first tell the element how to display before it can rely on `margin-left: auto;` or `margin-right: auto;`. For this specific application to achieve a centered button, I would do as follows:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 550px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 92px;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;  /*Using CSS to give the container the ability to alter its items' width/height // Hence - margin: auto now works properly.*/
/*display: table; Using a display: table; would really only apply if you were using a table structure in your HTML*/
  margin: 0 auto;  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css">
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">      
            <button class="btn">boutton</button>        
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: he wanna set btn horizontally NOT vertically.

Comment: @ElsaKarami The button (in this answer is right) because it is centered horizontally  as the OP wanted.

Comment: [Comments in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments) are written with `/* Comment */`. The `<!-- Comment -->` works only in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

mx-auto class for horizontally centering fixed-width block-level content that is, content that has display: block and a width set—by setting the horizontal margins to auto.
you can use flex-box to center the height.
and finally you can omitted  `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` from the `.btn` class

```
.container {
  max-width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 92px;
}
```