# How to make css layout to fit html content?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout similar to:

```
 <div>
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like for the div to only expand to as wide as my table becomes. My CSS:

```
.content {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: #solid 10px #000;
    background-color: rgba(105,100,100,0.8);
          }
```

I've tried adding `display: inline-block` it works but it sets my `table` to the left of the scree, here's the screenshot: [image](http://s21.postimg.org/rrum4cijb/image.jpg) I want it to be centered as well, how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [div with display:inline-block margin 0 auto not center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313276/div-with-displayinline-block-margin-0-auto-not-center)

Comment: @sodawillow how do I accept your answer? sorry I'm still new in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to your body (provided the `div` is a direct child of your `body` tag)

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

(in your CSS stylesheet)

Comment: do you mean like this `<body text-align: center> <div class="content"></div></body>` ? I tried that but didn't work, it stays the same, no changes at all

Answer (score 0):

You could work with translate here.

```
.content{
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center` to parent element of `div` with `display:inline-block`